# writeln img src to submit data to external system - Firefox and IE hanging

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have been scouring the depths of the web to find a solution to a problem I'm having. I'm relatively new to Javascript so forgive me.

Upon clicking the next button on my checkout page, a script is run which submits the data to the ecommerce system. I have added onto this a script which also takes the data and puts into an email marketing system we are using. The script looks to see if a checkbox is ticked. Ticked or not I'm using the code below to write an img and the src transfers the data.

This works flawlessly in Chrome and Safari but Firefox and IE do not load the next page and seem to wait for the return of the img (which of course doesn't exist), but the data is successfully added to the external system marketing system.

I would really appreciate any advice as I'm soon to loose my hair on this one.

```
document.getElementById("idBtnNext").addEventListener("click", AddContact, false);

function AddContact(){
    var bemail = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEEMAIL')[0].value;
    var btitle = document.getElementsByName('INVOICESALUTATION')[0].value;
    var bfirstname = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEFIRSTNAME')[0].value;
    var blastname = document.getElementsByName('INVOICELASTNAME')[0].value;
    var baddressline1 = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEADDRESS1')[0].value;
    var baddressline2 = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEADDRESS2')[0].value;
    var bcity = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEADDRESS3')[0].value;
    var bstate = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEADDRESS4')[0].value;
    var bmobile = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEMOBILE')[0].value;
    var bhome = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEPHONE')[0].value;
    var bcompany = document.getElementsByName('INVOICECOMPANY')[0].value;
    var bcountry = document.getElementsByName('LocationInvoiceCountry')[0].value;
    var bpostcode = document.getElementsByName('INVOICEPOSTALCODE')[0].value;

if (document.getElementById('idINVOICEPRIVACY').checked == false)
    {
        document.writeln('<img src="https://app.bronto.com/public/?q=direct_add&fn=Public_DirectAddForm&id=XXXXXXXX&email='+bemail+'&field1=title,set,'+btitle+'&field2=firstname,set,'+bfirstname+'&field3=lastname,set,'+blastname+'&field4=addressline1,set,'+baddressline1+'&field5=addressline2,set,'+baddressline2+'&field6=city,set,'+bcity+'&field7=county,set,'+bstate+'&field8=country,set,'+bcountry+'&field9=mobile,set,'+bmobile+'&field10=home,set,'+bhome+'&field11=company,set,'+bcompany+'&field12=postcode,set,'+bpostcode+'&field13=ItemsInCart,set,0&field14=Item1ImageURL,set,&field15=Item1Name,set,&field16=Item1URL,set,&list17=0bbf03ec0000000000000000000000f59720&list18=0bbf03ec0000000000000000000000f59809&createCookie=1" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt=""/>');
    return true;
    }

else if (document.getElementById('idINVOICEPRIVACY').checked == true)
    {
        document.writeln('<img src="https://app.bronto.com/public/?q=direct_add&fn=Public_DirectAddForm&id=XXXXXX&email='+bemail+'&field1=title,set,'+btitle+'&field2=firstname,set,'+bfirstname+'&field3=lastname,set,'+blastname+'&field4=addressline1,set,'+baddressline1+'&field5=addressline2,set,'+baddressline2+'&field6=city,set,'+bcity+'&field7=county,set,'+bstate+'&field8=country,set,'+bcountry+'&field9=mobile,set,'+bmobile+'&field10=home,set,'+bhome+'&field11=company,set,'+bcompany+'&field12=postcode,set,'+bpostcode+'&field13=ItemsInCart,set,0&field14=Item1ImageURL,set,&field15=Item1Name,set,&field16=Item1URL,set,&transactional=1&createCookie=1" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt=""/>');
    return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you add a -full- example at jsfiddle? So we can follow it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kwe5tn6n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the behavior caused by the way how do you want to write an HTML element into a page. For your propose I think I got a better way:

So the first change is to add an img emelent that is not visible:

```
<img src="" id="hiddenImg" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="visibility:hidden">
<!-- You can also use display:none; -->
```

The second one is to change your Javascript:

```
function AddContact()
{
    ... lines skipped ...

    var targetUrlStr = "";
    if (document.getElementById('idINVOICEPRIVACY').checked == false)
    {
     targetUrlStr = 'https://app.bronto.com/public/<url cut here>';
    } else if (document.getElementById('idINVOICEPRIVACY').checked == true) {
     targetUrlStr = 'https://app.bronto.com/public/<url cut here>';
    }
    document.getElementById("hiddenImg").src = targetUrlStr;
    return true;
 }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you so very much! This has done just the job after days trying to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this @reporter but your suggestion regarding my original query doesn't appear to be working in Safari. Do you have any idea why this is or a way around it? Thanks.

Comment: I tested it with a quite old version of Safaribrowser and it did work. Try following extra change: `function start(){document.getElementById("idBtnNext").addEventListener("click", AddContact, false);}`and `<body onLoad="start()">`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it and it didn't work. When I test the code outside our website it works but as soon as it is live it doesn't work in Safari. I know this is a vague question but do you know what sort of thing to look for that may affect the JavaScript?

Comment: No, because "A picture says more than thousand words". Programming remotly is quite hard and creates a lot of misunderstandings.