# How to call javascript function from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am stucked in the middle of my code and need help.
I am creating a web application using jsp. Here is my code:

```
<%@include file="dbconnection.jsp"%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <H1></H1>
    <script language="JavaScript">
 function showdata(ctr) {
 switch (ctr) {
case 1:
    <%ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select value from Authors;") ;  %>
    <% 
    int c=0;
     while(rs.next()){ 
        String result=rs.getString(1);
        c++;
    %>
    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<A HREF = "#" ONCLICK="Nextdata(<%=c%>)"><%=result%></A>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');
    <% } %>
    document.write('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">');
    break;
case 2:
    alert("xyz");
     break;
     }
}
function Nextdata(count)
{
 switch (count) {
    case 1:
         alert("Hi");
        break;
 }
}
</script>
 <TABLE>
           <%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select title from Books;") ;%>
            <% 
            int counter=0;
             while(resultset.next()){ 
                String result=resultset.getString(1);
                counter++;
            %>
            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:showdata(<%=counter%>)"><%=result%></a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>
            <% } %>
  </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When i click on a particular link then `showdata` function gets called after that i am clicking on another link for which the code is written inside `showdata()` to call `Nextdata()` function. But this `Nextdata` function doesn't get called why so? where is my mistake? Please help.

Comment: Have you already tried to execute the pure generated html code? did any errors in the error console occure?

Comment: No errors... when i run my code i get multiple links one below the other .. when i click on a particular link i get another set of links and after that when i click on those links there i should get alert box but i am not getting it

Comment: @Dimple please create a jsfiddle with your generated html and javascript code

Comment: Check if you are getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: How it is done i don't know do you have any links related to it?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in my browser console only thing is after clicking on link i get data but around url i get connecting symbol

Comment: @Dimple http://jsfiddle.net Please give us a chance taking a look. Ultimatly you have nothing to lose.

Comment: try putting an alert at the very first line in the Nextdata() function. You will know if your function is getting called ?

Comment: Right Nitish NextData() is not getting called.

Comment: Any suggesstions on how can NextData() be called I tried putting it at different places

Comment: @Dimple It would be much easier if you would followed my advice and create an jsfiddle with your pure html code (what the browser received).

Comment: As @reporter is suggesting, it would help if you could share the generated HTML in your browser.. simply view source of your page and paste the contents here.. if you are unable to use jsFiddle

Comment: I copied my code inside html part in jsfiddle and in result section i am getting this:  <%@include file="dbconnection.jsp"%>
<%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT title from categoryInfoTable where CID in(select CID from categoryConfigTable where parentCID = 'NULL');") ;%> <% int counter=0; while(resultset.next()){ String link=resultset.getString(1); counter++; %> <% } %>
<%=link%>

Comment: @dimple, not this code. When you run your application and load this jsp on a web browser, we would like to see the generated html code from the browser. Not the jsp code you have written..

Answer (score 0):

You just cant nest the javascript functions, unless and until you are sure that the nested function 'NextData()' is not going be used outside the scope of
'ShowData()' function.

Just try to put the 'NextData()' outside the scope of 'ShowData()'

This may work out for you..!!

Comment: I did put Nextdata() outside the scope of showdata() but still the same

Comment: showdata() is replaced by displaydata() so don't get confused sry for inconvienience

Answer (score 0):

When i run jsp my source is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1></H1>
    <script language="JavaScript">
function NextData(ctrr)

{
 switch (ctrr) {
    case 1:
         alert("function 3");
        break;
    case 2:
         alert("function 3");
        break;
    case 3:
        alert("function 3");
         break;
     case 4:
         alert("function 4");
          break;
     case 5:
         alert("function 5");
          break;
 }
}

</script>
    <script language="JavaScript">


function displayData(ctr) {



 switch (ctr) {
case 1:



    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<A HREF ="javascript:NextData(1)">Spotlight</A>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<A HREF ="javascript:NextData(2)">Oryx highlights</A>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<A HREF ="javascript:NextData(3)">Little Taster</A>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">');



    break;
case 2:


    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(1)">Spotlight</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(2)">Simply the Best</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(3)">Juke box</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(4)">100 Greatest Album/Single</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(5)">List All Artists</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(6)">List All Albums</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(7)">Arabic</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(8)">Hindi</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(9)">Pop</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(10)">Rock</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(11)">Jazz & Blues</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(12)">Country</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(13)">Classical</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(14)">Dance</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(15)">Easy Listening</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(16)">World Music</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(17)">Relaxation</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(18)">Malayalam</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(19)">Tamil</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(20)">Far East</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(21)">Oryx Radio</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<table><tr><td>');
    document.write('<a href="JavaScript:NextData(22)">Audio Book</a>');
    document.write('</td></tr></table>');

    document.write('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">');
     break;
case 3:
   alert("function 3");
    break;
case 4:
    alert("function 4");
     break;
case 5:
    alert("function 5");
     break;
case 6:
    alert("function 6");
     break;
case 7:
    alert("function 7");
     break;
case 8:
    alert("function 8");
     break;
case 9:
    alert("function 9");
     break;
case 10:
    alert("function 10");
     break;
     }

}


</script>


 <TABLE>


            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(1)">Broadcast Video</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(2)">Interactive Audio</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(3)">Interactive Movies</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(4)">Trailers</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(5)">Interactive Trailers</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(6)">Interactive Shorts</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(7)">PA</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(8)">Young Travellers</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(9)">MISC</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>

            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a href="javascript:displayData(10)">Games</a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>


  </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And on clicking on link i get this as source:

```
<table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(1)">Spotlight</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(2)">Simply the Best</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(3)">Juke box</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(4)">100 Greatest Album/Single</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(5)">List All Artists</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(6)">List All Albums</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(7)">Arabic</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(8)">Hindi</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(9)">Pop</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(10)">Rock</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(11)">Jazz & Blues</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(12)">Country</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(13)">Classical</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(14)">Dance</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(15)">Easy Listening</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(16)">World Music</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(17)">Relaxation</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(18)">Malayalam</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(19)">Tamil</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(20)">Far East</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(21)">Oryx Radio</a></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:NextData(22)">Audio Book</a></td></tr></table><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">
```

Comment: There is nothing apparently wrong with the code. Which browser are you using? If you are using chrome, and you are not getting the alerts, try replacing alert() with console.log().. probably you have set the option to "Do not show alerts from this page" in chrome. Check if your console.log is coming in your browser console...

Comment: m using firefox and if u have viewed my 1st page sourcecode then there alerts are working !!

Comment: I could take a look and I think there is -in my eyes- a general problem in your concept  and also think the Internet Explorer will show the same effect like Firefox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854771/writeln-img-src-to-submit-data-to-external-system-firefox-and-ie-hanging/28856515#28856515 shows another case, where mentioned a similar (note: similar is not the same) issue. What exactly did you want do to?

Comment: I want to show hierarchy of data using links i.e. when i click on one link i should see the data inside it then again when i click on particular link i should see another data and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your defined function name is Nextdata()
and your generated HTML is calling a function Next**D**ata()

Check is this is the error?

In your browser console check if your are getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: NextData is not defined"

Comment: Before your answer i checked and corrected it but still the same

Comment: okay.. as mentioned earlier, it is difficult to guess where exactly things are going wrong unless we have a look at the complete html source.. can you view source and select all and paste here? the whole source in your browser.

Comment: i selected all only earlier

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to investigate the issue and found out -in this case thanks to Internet Explorer- the reason. Also it confirmed my comment in answer two (it came from op himself):

When you executes `document.write()` the IE and FF generate a new blank page. The effect is that the javascript function `NextData()` does not exists. Are it really sure that both browsers creates a new page? Yes, because `history.goBack(-1)` does work and show the first view again.
So the browsers are unable to execute a non existing function.

Any solution?: Maybe...

**One** way to solve this issue is create two div elements, that contains the first table and second one contains the ***appended*** target table. The hide the first and show the second. [Javascript: AppendChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867003/javascript-appendchild) will help you to understand what I meant.

P.S.: There exists more than one way to solve this, but do never ever use `document.write()`. As you can see, this method shows in some browsers unexpected behavior.